# ¿"Antes de nada" o "antes que nada"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos

Estaba escribiendo una respuesta cuando me surgió la duda: ¿qué es más correcto, decir "antes de nada" o "antes que nada"?

[Fundéu menciona "antes de nada"](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/ante-todo-496/) en un artículo. Sin embargo, veo que [la Universidad Francisco Marrooquín](http://educacion.ufm.edu/antes-que-nada/) de Guatemala hablan de "antes que nada".

Es por ello que dudo sobre si son igualmente válidas, si tienen distinción según los países o si son, llana y simplemente, iguales.

Comment: yo diría "antes que nada" o "antes de algo" o "antes de cualquier cosa" e incluso en algunos casos la sustituimos por "primero que todo"

Comment: En España, ambas son usuales y correctas.

Comment: En México es más común "antes que nada".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bueno, si hacemos caso a [la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=WO1Ix87I4D6gmdE155) ambas son válidas (e incluso "*antes de que*").

> 1. Normalmente va seguido de un complemento precedido de la preposición **de**: "Quince días **antes de** su muerte [...]"
>
> [...]
>
> 3. **antes que** o **antes de que**. Con significado temporal, ambas construcciones son válidas. [...] Del cruce de **antes que** y **antes de**, surgió **antes de que**, variante de la locución conjuntiva que algunos gramáticos censuraron en un principio por dequeísta, pero que hoy se acepta como válida.

No creo que la forma "antes de que" pueda aplicar a "nada", pero tanto "antes de" como "antes que" son válidas con significado temporal, y puede ir acompañadas de "nada" como complemento, con el significado de "cualquier cosa".

La entrada de la RAE para [nada](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=1kP4fcZLUDXX2H0ASBkf) por supuesto valida el "antes de" como locución adverbial con el significado de "Antes de cualquier cosa".

Curiosamente, la entrada para [primero/a](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rpVvFSy2sD6XdbqzWb) indica que existe la forma "primero que nada." con el significado de "antes de nada o antes que nada"

> **primero que nada**. En el habla coloquial se emplea esta expresión con el sentido de *‘antes de nada o antes que nada’*.

Así que ambas formas son válidas e igualmente correctas. La predilección por una u otra puede depender del hablante, más que del país.

Answer (score 0):

En resumen:

Formas coloquiales:

- "Primero que nada"
- "Primero que todo"

Formas más cultas:

- "Antes de nada"
- "Antes que nada"

Lo anterior, según la RAE.

Comment: gracias! Sería interesante indicar la fuente exacta de donde sacas este contenido

Comment: La fuente de esta respuesta parece ser la respuesta de @Diego 

Comment: Bienvenida Adriana Ma. Sería ideal complementar tu respuesta con las referencias de la RAE o algunos ejemplos, que expliquen el motivo de tu respuesta.